# Making checkbox checked by exploding value

Tags: php, explode, implode

Man this makes no sense I tried to figure this out for hours and searched all over this site.  In the DB, the user_level is 1,2,3 as a value I imploded. I am displaying checkboxes and I want them to be checked when the value matches what is in the DB.  This worked perfectly when there was only a single value in the DB like 1 or 2 for user_level.  Now with 1,2,3, I simply exploded the value then used in_array() to result a result and if so add the checkbox.  For some reason this don't work, random boxes seem to be checked.  Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_level FROM table";
$result = query_db($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$field_names =  array(MEMBER    => 'Member', 
              VISITOR => 'Visitor');


foreach ( $field_names as $key => $value )
{

    $thePostIdArray = explode(',', $key);

    //print_r($thePostIdArray); // testing output


    $selected = ( in_array($row['user_level'], $thePostIdArray) ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';


    $options .= '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$perm_type.'[]" '.$selected.' value="'.$key.'"> '.$value. ' ';

}
```

The $selected value should output the "checked" value on the correct checkboxes but it is not.

Comment: You should dump `$row` before the foreach to make sure it contains what you're looking for.  And the value for `$field_names` doesn't seem to make sense... Actually, nevermind on `$row` because it's not actually used anywhere.  Is that the whole section of code or did you edit some things out?  Also.. if you are supposed to be using `$row` and there are several rows... you need to do `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { .... }` for each row you expect back... (and you should use msqli_ or pdo bc it's safer, lol... I will stop updating this now, sorry!)

Comment: The $row is displaying the user_level value from the DB.  When there is only 1 digit in the user_level this works perfectly.  It is only when the commas are added that is screws up.  I think the in_array() is not working somehow.

Comment: Can you post an example of what is returned in $row?  And are `MEMBER` and `VISITOR` constants in `$fieldnames`?  If not, what is going on there exactly?  I can't tell what you want to do.... how many checkboxes are there?  Two?

Comment: $row results values imploded into the database like "1,2,3" and "1,2". When I didn't use implode and it resulted in single values like $row = 1 and $row = 2, this worked perfectly.  All I changed was the implode and now it doesnt work.

Comment: where is the `implode` you keep talking about? so now it is saved like `insert into my_table (my_field) values ("1,2,3")`?  Right before you do `$thePostIdArray = explode(',', $key);`, add a line that displays the `$key`.. you're not even using `$row`, which is supposedly the data from your table... you're using `$key`

Comment: The implode is in another file.  It works perfectly.  The constants MEMBER and VISITOR hold the value of 1 and 2.  Like MEMBER is equal to 1, as in a member has a level value of 1.  The $key represents the constant.  When I echo the $key, values 1 and 2 are displayed.  The $row displays data from the DB.  It matches $key like 1 or 2 to see if matches the $row.  This worked perfectly until I separated the values with commas.   When $row was just 1 or 2 and matched with $key like $row['user_level] == $key, it matched.  Now using the in_array() with an exploded array it doesnt work.

Comment: Haha Ifixed it thanks!  I had to switch $row['user_level"] and $key in the in_array() haha.  Not sure what I was thinking.  Thanks guys :)

Comment: Yeah when you made me explain how it works it made me realize what I had done wrong thanks :)  I only had two hours of sleep last night perhaps that is what is making my mind turn to mush.

Comment: yaaaayyyy!  lol... good job.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

`array(MEMBER ...` is incorrect. `MEMBER` and `VISITOR` like that are undefined constants (unless you haven't shown a `define()` call you're doing elsewhere). PHP will "politely" correct them to be strings, but will issue warnings.

Your foreach() loop then takes this new array and loops on its contents:

```
foreach ( $field_names as $key => $value ) {
    $thePostIdArray = explode(',', $key);
```

But at this point `$key` is just a STRING, e.g. 'MEMBER' or 'VISITOR'. It's not array, so there's nothing to explode on.

```
$foo = explode(',', 'member');
```

will produce a single element array containing `0 => 'member'`, so now you DO have an array. And that, purely by accident, would let your `in_array` call work. But this entire sequence is pointless and utterly redundant.

Note that `in_array` does a case-sensitive comparison:

```
$arr = array('FOO');
var_dump('foo', $arr);
```

will return a boolean false, because `FOO != foo` in this case.

Comment: Yes the constant is defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')
         or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$query  = "select user_level from test.my_table";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db); 

/*
mysql> select user_level from my_table;
+------------+
| user_level |
+------------+
| 1,2,3      |
| 4          |
| 5,6        |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

*/

/*

$rows = array();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}

print "<pre>".print_r($rows,true)."</pre>"; 


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_level] => 1,2,3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_level] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_level] => 5,6
        )

)
*/

$my_checkboxes = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven'); 
$group = 0; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
   $row_values = explode(',',$row['user_level']); 

   /*
   print "<pre>".print_r($row_values,true)."</pre>"; 

   Array
   (
       [0] => 1
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 3
   )
   Array
   (
       [0] => 4
   )
   Array
   (
       [0] => 5
       [1] => 6
   ) 
   */

   print "<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block'>";

   foreach ($my_checkboxes as $value => $label)
   {
      $selected = (in_array(($value+1), $row_values)) ? "checked='checked'" : ''; 

      print "<input type='checkbox' name='group$group' value='$value' $selected/>$label<br/>";  
   } 

   print "</div><br/><br/>";
   $group++; 
}


?>
```

[image]

and the HTML the PHP outputs (view source):

```
<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block'><input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='0' checked='checked'/>one<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='1' checked='checked'/>two<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='2' checked='checked'/>three<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='3' />four<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='4' />five<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='5' />six<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group0' value='6' />seven<br/>
</div><br/><br/>

<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block'><input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='0' />one<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='1' />two<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='2' />three<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='3' checked='checked'/>four<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='4' />five<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='5' />six<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='6' />seven<br/>
</div><br/><br/>

<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline-block'><input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='0' />one<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='1' />two<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='2' />three<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='3' />four<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='4' checked='checked'/>five<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='5' checked='checked'/>six<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='group2' value='6' />seven<br/>
</div><br/><br/>
```